# Trouble with apostrophe in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following case statement in sql

```
case when fake.join in (''Women'') then ''Women's'' else ''Other'' end'
```

in my stored procedure.  I'm having trouble getting it to come through as "Women's" and the only thing i can find to deal with this says to do ''Women''s'') but that makes the apostrophe disappear. I need to keep the apostrophe. Please help! Thanks

Comment: Please specify the database and show a more complete example.

Comment: Are those two single quotes around each string?

Comment: yes two single quotes

Comment: why do you need the database? I'm just asking how to get an apostrophe in a string to actually show up in the final data

Comment: @user6114185 because different databases have different syntax

Comment: Could be wrong because we dont have much to go on, but seems as simple as `then 'women''s' else` - two single quotes between n and s in Womens

Comment: Specify the RDBMS (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL) not database. We don't care what your database is called.

Comment: it is Miscrosoft SQL server management studio

Comment: ander2ed, thank you, but that does not work. That makes it come through as Womens without the apostrophe. I need Women's

Comment: Please show the full statement so we can see it  in context.

Comment: here is the case: 'case when sm.LegalName in (''Brigham & Women Hospital'', ''Brigham & Women Faulkner Hospital'') then ''Brigham & Women''s Hospital''
when sm.LegalName in (''Newton Wellesley Hospital'', ''Massachusetts General Hospital'') then sm.LegalName
else ''Other'' end'

Comment: @user6114185 please update your question with that information, it's not as useful in comment form and can be easily missed.

Answer (score 5):

If this is truly a standalone statement, then it should look like this:

```
case when fake.join in ('Women') then 'Women''s' else 'Other' end
```

If you're building a string with some dynamic SQL (which is kind of what it looks like with all the apostrophe escaping), it should look like this:

```
case when fake.join in (''Women'') then ''Women''''s'' else ''Other'' end'
```

EDIT: Here it is with the fuller snippet you provided (just note the 4 apostrophe's between the 'n' and 's'):

```
case when sm.LegalName in (''Brigham & Women Hospital'', ''Brigham & Women Faulkner Hospital'') then ''Brigham & Women''''s Hospital'' 
    when sm.LegalName in (''Newton Wellesley Hospital'', ''Massachusetts General Hospital'') then sm.LegalName 
    else ''Other'' end'
```

You can then feed a string including this to sp_executesql and it should give you what you're after.

Comment: i think this is getting close. The other thing i suppose i forget to include, is that there is another word after womens. So it needs to include the next word, too. so 
case when fake.join in (''Women hospital'') then ''Women''''s''  hospital "" else ''Other'' end'

Comment: Updated to include a version with the fuller snippet you provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the resulting string to be `'Women's'`, then use `'''Women''s'''`:

```
PRINT '''Women''s'''
```

Results in:

```
'Women's'
```